# How many numbers such that created from these numbers have $5$ digits and divide $30$?

Tags: combinatorics

Given $6$ digit numbers: $0,1,2,3,4,5,6$, how many numbers such that created from these numbers have $5$ digits and divisible by $30$?
For example: $30300, 12360,...$

Here is what I got:

Let a number form: $\overline{a_1a_2a_3a_4a_5}$

Because it divisible $30$ so $a_5=0$

And we have to find: $a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4 \vdots3$

Thus, $$a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4 \in \begin{Bmatrix}3;6;9;12;15;18;21;24\end{Bmatrix}$$

This is related to the Euler's candy problems, and I just find the answers for $3,6$: $C_5^3+C_8^3$ ways

But in the $9;12;15;21$ case I got stuck with: $a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4$ where $1\leq a_1 \leq 6$ and $0 \leq a_i \leq 6, i=\overline{2,4}$

Comment: $\overline{a_1a_2a_3a_4a_5}$ means $1296a_1+216a_2+36a_3+6a_4+a_5$. That's it ?

Comment: $6(a_1+...+a_4)\equiv 0 \mod 30\iff a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4\equiv 0 \mod 5$. Isn't it ?

Comment: Do you mean "are divisible by $30$"? A number divides $30$ if $30$ is divisible by that number.

Comment: Yes I mean divisible by 30 @JohnDouma

Comment: @PeterPhipps I forgot ^^ sorry

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nifty use of generating functions.

Let $a_{k,n}$ be the number of ways a sequence of $k$ digits from $D=\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ can have the sum $n$. If we concatenate a sequence of length $j$ and a sequence of length $k$, then the sums of the joined sequence have possible sums

$$ a_{j+k,n} = \sum_{m=0}^n a_{j,m} a_{k,n-m} $$

This looks just like the formula for coefficients in polynomial multiplication.

Based on that idea, consider the generating functions

$$ f_k(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{6k} a_{k,n} x^n $$

If we concatenate strings of length $j$ and $k$, the total number of possibilities is found just by polynomial multiplication:

$$ f_{j+k}(x) = f_j(x) f_k(x) $$

The case of one digit is

$$ f_1(x) = x^0 + x^1 + x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + x^5 + x^6 $$

So for multiple digits,

$$ f_k(x) = (1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6)^k $$

For this problem, we want just the parts of $f_4(x)$ where the exponent of $x$ is a multiple of $3$. The standard generating function trick for this sort of filtering is to plug in the complex values of $x$ where $x^3=1$ and take the average result:

$$ \sum_{m=0}^8 a_{4,3m} = \frac 13 \big(f_4(1) + f_4(e^{2\pi i/3}) + f_4(e^{4\pi i/3})\big) $$

$$ \sum_{m=0}^8 a_{4,3m} = \frac 13 (7^4 + 1^4 + 1^4) = 801 $$

There are $801$ such numbers. (And this makes sense intuitively, since "about" one third of the possible $7^4$ combinations of four digits should be divisible by 3.)